# how do you connect to oracle using pyodbc

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle db using pyodbc, getting errors. The examples include ms sql server driver:

in my /etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini, I have this entry:

```
[test_con]
Driver=Oracle
Description=data repository db
Trace=Yes
ServerName=//db1.example.com:1521/db2_svc1


import pyodbc
cnxn=pyodbc.connect('DSN=test_con, UID=user_id, PWD=passwd123')
```

I get this error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM012', '[IM012] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]DRIVER keyword syntax error (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: if you fixed this issue, can you please help to fix mine?

Comment: This worked for me https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Oracle-from-RHEL-or-Centos

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import pyodbc
connectString = 'Driver={Microdsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=<host>:<port>/<db>.<host>;uid= <username>;pwd=<password>'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connectString)
```

Read some docs ;) https://sites.google.com/site/bcgeopython/examples/getting-the-pyodbc-module

Comment: @ValeiryG, I looked at that link, it is SQL Driver, I am on a linux server. I tried it anyway: 
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not                                                                                       found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Answer (score 7):

I came here looking for an answer to this question, but instead found an answer elsewhere to a more general question that I'd like to share.  You can very simply connect to an Oracle db without pyodbc, using the cx_Oracle library.  Check out the installation instructions below:

https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html

Starter code below:

```
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_19_10")

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(
user="username",
password="password",
dsn="address")

cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Comment: The latest version of cx_Oracle was renamed to python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  Usage is the same as above.  Install instructions are [here](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html). Compared with pyodbc, the python-oracledb driver has the same standard DB API as pyodbc with many extensions for Oracle, is faster, and doesn't need any extra libraries to be installed (i.e. doesn't need Oracle Instant Client).

Answer (score 2):

pyodbc maintainer did an excellent job at documenting how to install Oracle ODBC driver and then how to connect to the database. It worked for me: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Oracle-from-RHEL-or-Centos

Answer (score 0):

The code below is for mssql on Mac OS and it assumes that you installed unixODBC using:

```
$ brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
```

and that you have edited the two odbc config files:

1. **/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/etc/odbcinst.ini**

   [FreeTDS]

   Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL on MacOS

   Driver=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.80/lib/libtdsodbc.0.so

   Setup=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.80/lib/libtdsodbc.0.so

   FileUsage=1
2. Edit **~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini**

   [sql_server]

   Driver=FreeTDS

   Server=put_ip_here

   Port=1433

== Code:

```
import pyodbc

connection_string = "Driver={{FreeTDS}};Server={};"\
"Database={};UID={};PWD={};"\
.format(db_host, db_name, db_user, db_password)

with pyodbc.connect(connection_string) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM aTable")
    ...
```

Comment: MSSQL example doesn't address oracle connection question

Comment: The question is for Oracle while FreeTDS driver is for MsSQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The reply has been late but can be useful for future reader.

Install:

- oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
- oracle-instantclient12.2-odbc-12.2.0.1.0-2.x86_64.rpm

From:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

```
sudo rpm -Uvh oracle-instantclient12.2-*
```

set ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
```

In /etc/odbcinst.ini set:

```
[Oracle_test]
Description=Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 12c
Driver=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1
FileUsage=1
Driver Logging=7
UsageCount=1
```

In Python shell:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Oracle_test};Host=1.1.1.1;Port=1521;Service Name=orcl.local;User ID=test1;Password=test1')
>>> print(conn)
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x7f6acb2c4c00>
```

Hopefully it helps someone.

PS: You can also set the driver in /etc/ld.so.conf as

```
/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
```

Run:
ldconfig